# In the novel, did Mirri Maz Duur intentionally harm Khal Drogo and his unborn son?

Tags: game-of-thrones

SPOILER ALERT!!! DO NOT CONTINUE IF YOU HAVE NOT READ 'A GAME OF THRONES', THE FIRST NOVEL IN 'A SONG OF ICE AND FIRE', OR WATCHED THE ENTIRE FIRST SEASON OF THE TELEVISION SHOW "GAME OF THRONES".

My question is mostly about the ritual Mirri performed (at Dany's frantic and desperate insistence) to save Drogo's life. Although we must believe Maz Duur had initially attempted to heal Drogo (I believe she had truly attempted to heal him to the best of her ability). Although it may be a little ambiguous whether she truly did try to heal him, it is fairly unambiguous after Dany's final confrontation with Duur that with the blood magic ritual to save Drogo ("death must pay for life") she had intentionally deceived Dany to the ends of killing her son and neutralizing Drogo. Duur explains to Dany that she had not in fact 'saved her' from the atrocities of the Dothraki, and that by the death of Dany and Drogo's son, countless lives had been saved and untold misery and suffering averted, by the simple virtue that the 'stallion who would mount the world' would no longer live to conquer the globe. These questions have NOT been asked, and not answered in the previous question, which is about Mirri Maz Duur's treatment of Khal Drogos wound. This question is about events that happened after that incident, and revolves around Dany and her unborn child. It has been marked a duplicate, but is not even close to the same question and is not referring to the same events. So my questions specifically:

1. Was Mirri Maz Duur plotting and weighing her options for vengeance and action during all of her time with Dany? Or did she just seize the opportunity at the end, when Dany was desperate and easily manipulated?
2. How had the baby been dead inside Dany for so long? It is described as rotten and decomposed, skin and muscle sliding off the bones, and full of maggots and worms. I believe it is said or implied that the baby had been dead inside her for years. And why was the bay partially dragon?
3. Was the baby perfectly normal, fully human and healthy, until the ritual to revive Drogo began? And if so, was it the act of Ser Jorah carrying Dany into the tent when Duur was 'dancing with the dead' that 'no one must look upon' that caused the death and supernatural deformation and decay of the child? What would have happened had Ser Jorah not taken Dany into the tent during the ritual?

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: Related: [Did Daenerys' stillborn have dragon features?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7078/21267)